# LUIS incorrectly recognizes utterances

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I’m working on a LUIS app, based on a car dealer where users can search for car models.  I setup the intent called “FindCar” to work with utterance “find [color] [car]”.

1. When I test the app and submit an utterance “Find Red Mustang”, it responds with a high percentage for intent “FindCar” but always has a low percentage for intent “None”.  Why does it always return a low percentage to “None”, even if I the utterance matches what I setup for FindCar?
2. When I submit a completely different utterance like “Build big house”, I was expecting to return a high percentage for intention “None”.  Instead, it still returns a high percentage to “FindCar”.  Why is that?

Comment: have you trained your model?

Answer (score 3):

1. LUIS will return all intents with the associated confidence levels for each. This is when you set the `verbose` setting to true in the Publish window. This allows the developer to view all intent confidence levels so you have full control over which intent you wish to use. Most cases, you will always go with the highest confidence scoring intent.
2. Make sure that your `None` intent is trained as well with a few examples of non car related utterances (for this example). Also, make sure to train and publish after you update your model as your endpoint will not reflect the most up to date language model until you re-publish. This is a very common overlooked step. Re-publish often!

Answer (score 1):

1. As Kevin indicated, LUIS will return all the prediction scores if the `verbose` flag is set to true. This flag is by default set to true. As long as the correct intent is the highest scoring intent and a decent score gap between the next intents I wouldn't worry too much. That said, the scores for the other intents matter, if you're using the utterance "Find car dealership" for a `FindCarDealership` intent I would expect a narrower gap in scoring than between `FindCar` and `None`.
2. Can you provide the exact score for this? Personally I consider scores over .8 to be high (here the prediction is most likely right), but I also consider anything below .7 to be in definite need of training. 
   As Kevin said, you will need to train the `None` intent by adding some labeled utterances. In addition to this it'll help to understand that LUIS performs syntactic analysis; meaning it's looking at the structure and placement of words in an utterance, not the actual meaning (semantic analysis) of a word. Token lengths (word length in this case) do matter.